# User agent stylesheet - attribute selector img[align="left" i]

Tags: html, css

In Chrome when I create a left aligned image

```
<img src="images/watchmen.jpg" alt="Watch men (2009)" align="left" title="Watch men movie cover" />
```

in applied styles I see:

```
img[Attributes Style] {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

img[align="left" i] {         user agent stylesheet
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

I was wondering what does **i** mean in context of img[align="left" i]? The rule is applied and there is really 3px right margin, though when I write the rule in css, lint gives me error.

Comment: It means it’s case-insensitive.

Comment: Update your lint.